# Writing animation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that animates a sentence (writes and deletes it using "innerHTML"), in this example, I can only use one per element, and I wanted to call it in HTML and indicate the phrases in a PHP variable. So I wanted to use only 1 Javascript file for multiple elements.

Example of what I want:

```
<div id = "Phrases" onload = "animWrite (phrase, element id);"></div>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/yLireJ/qoaw2ce5/6/

```
<div id="sbFrases">&#9654; </div>
```

Comment: Have you heard of functions maybe? Create function that does the same and pass string as parameter, use that parameter instead of array with words

Answer (score 1):

Function-ize it so you can reuse it:

```js
var FrasesA = ['I\'m brazilian', ' and I need help', 'because', 'I want to be a', 'Web Designer'];

var FrasesB = ['I\'m english', ' and I need help', 'because', 'I want to be', 'normal', ':p'];

function typer(phrases, id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);

  function escrever(str, done) {
      var char = str.split('').reverse();
      var typer = setInterval(function() {
          if (!char.length) {
              clearInterval(typer);
              return setTimeout(done, 500);
          }
          var next = char.pop();
          div.innerHTML += next;
      }, 100);
  }

  function limpar(done) {
      var char = div.innerHTML;
      var nr = char.length;
      var typer = setInterval(function() {
          if (nr-- == 2) {
              clearInterval(typer);
              return done();
          }
          div.innerHTML = char.slice(0, nr);
      }, 100);
  }

  function rodape(conteudos) {
      var atual = -1;
    function prox(){
      if (atual < conteudos.length - 1) atual++;
      else atual = 0;
      var str = conteudos[atual];
      escrever(str, function(){
        limpar(prox);
      });
    }
    prox();
  }

  rodape(phrases);
}

typer(FrasesA, 'sbFrasesA')
typer(FrasesB, 'sbFrasesB')
```

```html
<div id="sbFrasesA">&#9654; </div>
<div id="sbFrasesB">&#9654; </div>
```